Strange relationship with Euler's number
I was playing around with $e$ (Euler's number) and found out that for any $a$ and $b$, $1-e^{\left(\frac{-a^2}{2b^2}\right)}\approx1$. Also when both numbers are $e$, the result is equivalent to $\frac{1}{9}$. More details: I found an interesting expression (from Expression with Euler number) and thought that I would find something useful to it, so I plugged in random values into Google and found out that no matter what numbers I use, it is either close to 1 or exactly one. Can someone explain to me why this is?

Are you saying that if you plug $a=e$ and $b=e$ into your expression ($1-e^{-a^2/2b^2}$), you got $1/9$? If so, you may want to recheck how you're doing your calculations.

That limit isn't true. There is no limit

When $a=b,$ whatever value, you get $1-\frac1{\sqrt e},$ not $\frac19.$

And are you suggesting that the value when $a=b=e$ has some bearing on the limit as $(a,b)\to\infty.$ The "also" seems to imply there is some relationship there.

It would be interesting if you include how you get $1$ in the limit

Welcome to Math.SE! ... Unfortunately, the new edit, which removes the limit, doesn't make the assertion any more sensible. ... Perhaps you could say something about how you were "playing around" with these values, and how that led you to suspect these relations. Someone may be able to help you spot errors in your intuition or formulate a plausible conjecture that better captures what you've seen. ... Good luck!

The limit given does not exist. For a 2-D limit to exist, the limit along every path toward the point (or in this case, every path diverging in both directions in the first quadrant) must result in the same value. We can see that taking the limit along the paths $a=b$ and $a=2b$, we respecitvely get
$$\lim_{(a,b)\to(\infty,\infty),a=b}1-e^{\frac{-a^2}{2b^2}}=1-e^\frac{-1}{2}$$
$$\lim_{(a,b)\to(\infty,\infty),a=2b}1-e^{\frac{-a^2}{2b^2}}=1-e^{-2}$$
Since these are not equal, this limit does not exist.
As to how/why you obtained 1 as the answer, I believe you evaluated the following limit, which exists and is different from the one you described:
$$\lim_{b\to\infty}\left(\lim_{a\to\infty}1-e^{\frac{-a^2}{2b^2}}\right)$$
$$=\lim_{b\to\infty}1-e^{-\infty}$$
$$=\lim_{b\to\infty}1$$
$$=1$$
Note again that this is only one of infinitely many paths for the original limit, all of which must be equal for the original limit to exist.
